# Craft 3 Field Plugin not firing $view->registerJs in entry versions

Tags: plugin-development, craft3, field

I am creating a Craft 3 plugin. It seems to work fine when editing regular entries but when I open a revision the JS I'm injecting using the below doesn't appear on the page.

```
$view->registerJs($js, View::POS_HEAD);
```

This does work on regular entries. Any ideas?

Comment: I think this may be a bug as it doesn't work for the CKEditor plugin either. https://github.com/craftcms/ckeditor/issues/14

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is by design. Revisions are not meant to be editable.